# CellPadding not working for table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cellpadding

Using DOM elements trying to add cellPadding to a table:
why does

```
var FirstTabContent = document.createElement('div');
var Newtable = document.createElement('table');
Newtable.border = "1";
Newtable.cellpadding = "20px 20px 20px 20px";
///////////////
//populate table
///////////////
FirstTabContent.appendChild(Newtable);
return FirstTabContent.innerHTML;
```

return:

```
<table border="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <b>id</b>
         </td>
         <td>14079<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

where is the cellpadding?

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, `cellPadding` (with a capital P) corresponds to the `cellpadding` presentational attribute on the `table` element itself, which only accepts a single length or percentage:

```
Newtable.cellPadding = "20";
```

But if you're trying to apply cell padding to this generated table via CSS (as implied by the `20px 20px 20px 20px` value), you should use CSS, and with CSS, you need to set it on the `td` elements and not the table:

```
td {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Otherwise you will need to loop through all the cells in the table (once you add them) and set `style.padding` on them, which is just plain tedious.

If you really want to use the `cellPadding` property, note that you can only set a uniform padding this way if you use a pixel value, since it only accepts a single value.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `cellPadding` with an upper case `P`.

Setting `Newtable.cellPadding = "20px 20px 20px 20px"` might set the attribute to desired value but it will not produce the desired result. You can only [set it to a pixel or a percentage length](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-cellpadding):

```
Newtable.cellPadding = "20";
```